# Uncaught TypeError: this.each is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

While trying to create a inline datatable, I keep coming across this error. I have even tried copying the example code present in the documentary, directly!
The code given below is the working datatable code:

```html
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples
$(document).ready(function() {

 
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        ajax: {url:'https://api.myjson.com/bins/gcx26',
            crossDomain : true},

        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
        columns: [
            { data: "first_name" },
            { data: "last_name" },
            { data: "position" },
            { data: "office" },
            { data: "start_date" },
            { data: "salary", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' ) }
        ]
    } );
} );
    </script>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th width="18%">Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The code given here is when I tried to make it editable inline.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    editor = new $.fn.dataTable-editor.Editor( {
        ajax: {url:'https://api.myjson.com/bins/gcx26',
            crossDomain : true},
        table: "#example",
        fields: [ {
                label: "First name:",
                name: "first_name"
            }, {
                label: "Last name:",
                name: "last_name"
            }, {
                label: "Position:",
                name: "position"
            }, {
                label: "Office:",
                name: "office"
            }, {
                label: "Extension:",
                name: "extn"
            }, {
                label: "Start date:",
                name: "start_date",
                type: "datetime"
            }, {
                label: "Salary:",
                name: "salary"
            }
        ]
    } );
 
    // Activate an inline edit on click of a table cell
      $('#example').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
            editor.inline( this );
        } );
 
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: "Bfrtip",
         ajax: {url:'https://api.myjson.com/bins/gcx26',
            crossDomain : true},
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
        columns: [
            {
                data: null,
                defaultContent: '',
                className: 'select-checkbox',
                orderable: false
            },
            { data: "first_name" },
            { data: "last_name" },
            { data: "position" },
            { data: "office" },
            { data: "start_date" },
            { data: "salary", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' ) }
        ],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        buttons: [
            { extend: "create", editor: editor },
            { extend: "edit",   editor: editor },
            { extend: "remove", editor: editor }
        ]
    } );
} );
    </script>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th width="18%">Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me understand why this error is occurring and how to fix this issue.

Comment: pls use the snippet editor to add your code. for starters: you are missing the main jquery script.

Comment: `editor = new $.fn.dataTable-editor.Editor` is not valid JS. [The site](https://editor.datatables.net/manual/getting-started) says  `editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {`  - the latest JS is `https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js` and you have no CSS for any of the plugins

Comment: @rx2347 The code is using AJAX so a working snippet would not be possible

Comment: @mplungjan https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @mplungjan When I use ```$.fn.dataTable.Editor``` , I get another error: ```Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.Editor is not a constructor.``` When I looked this up, the suggestion was to use```$fn.datatable-editor```

Comment: @rx2347 I use that EVERY day around 10 times a day. I know the text. In THIS case OP cannot make a proper example because of the ajax

Comment: @HarshitPandey $fn.datatable-editor in JS means subtract editor from $fn.datatable so that is not a good suggestion. I know you get that error. I do not know why. I tried to make a [mcve] and got that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that we cant use `$.fn.dataTable-editor.Editor`, as @mplungjan said, all it does is it subtracts editor from `$fn.database`. We instead have to download a dependency: "Editor-1.9.2/js/dataTables.editor.js" from the [website](https://editor.datatables.net/download/index) itself. After downloading the file locally it is possible to run the code. This is the new and improved, working version of the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jqc-1.12.4/dt-1.10.20/b-1.6.1/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Editor-1.9.2/css/editor.dataTables.css">
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jqc-1.12.4/dt-1.10.20/b-1.6.1/sl-1.3.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Editor-1.9.2/js/dataTables.editor.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Editor-1.9.2/js/dataTables.editor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
        ajax: {url:'https://api.myjson.com/bins/gcx26',
            crossDomain : true},
        table: "#example",
        fields: [ {
                label: "First name:",
                name: "first_name"
            }, {
                label: "Last name:",
                name: "last_name"
            }, {
                label: "Position:",
                name: "position"
            }, {
                label: "Office:",
                name: "office"
            }, {
                label: "Extension:",
                name: "extn"
            }, {
                label: "Start date:",
                name: "start_date",
                type: "datetime"
            }, {
                label: "Salary:",
                name: "salary"
            }
        ]
    } );
 
    // Activate an inline edit on click of a table cell
      $('#example').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
            editor.inline( this );
        } );
 
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: "Bfrtip",
         ajax: {url:'https://api.myjson.com/bins/gcx26',
            crossDomain : true},
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
        columns: [
            {
                data: null,
                defaultContent: '',
                className: 'select-checkbox',
                orderable: false
            },
            { data: "first_name" },
            { data: "last_name" },
            { data: "position" },
            { data: "office" },
            { data: "start_date" },
            { data: "salary", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' ) }
        ],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        buttons: [
            { extend: "create", editor: editor },
            { extend: "edit",   editor: editor },
            { extend: "remove", editor: editor }
        ]
    } );
} );
    </script>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th width="18%">Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```